# coping pixels from an image to a black image for upscaling through nearest neighbor

Tags: for-loop, interpolation, pixel, image-resizing, nearest-neighbor

Im trying to upscale an image by coping one pixel and pasting it in 4 positions in new image. I'm unable to find a way to create a loop that copies 1 pixel and pastes in 4 positions of the new image.

```
image = cv2.imread("xyz.jpg")
##Creating a new black image
w, h = 1920, 1080
data = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
data[0:256, 0:256] = [256, 256, 256] 
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
img.save('my.png')
img.show() 
#copy and pasting pixels
for i in range(0,1079):
 for j in range(0,1919):
     img[i,j]=data[0:256]
     img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
img.save('new.png')
img.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want to transform a source image into a destination image you should, looping through all pixels of the destination image:

- back-transform the coordinates of the pixel in the source image,
- take the value of the back-transformed point in the source image (eventually using some interpolation method),
- use it to fill the value of the pixel in the destination image.

In this case, if I'm not misunderstanding your question, the transformation is a resize of the image by a factor of 2. So first you have to create the image of with proper dimensions (doubling width and height of the original image). Then, looping through every pixel of the new image, to fill their value you should back-transform its coordinates (hence divide them by 2), and get the value of the original image in that position. From what you said, it seems to me that you are not interested in interpolating the value for non-integer coordinates. If this was the case, you should simply cast the coordinates to integer values and then get the value in the source image.